# 401 Unauthorised Error Received

Tags: c#, parsing

I am using the habbo api to check if a name is valid. I'm receiving a 401 Unauthorised Error.

Below is the code I'm using. It worked when I copied my Cookie header in chrome and added that as a header. But is there another way and an actual fix?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using(WebClient WebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                WebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
                MessageBox.Show(WebClient.DownloadString("https://www.habbo.com/api/user/avatars/check-name?name=123"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The API `https://www.habbo.com/api/user/avatars/check-name` what you are referring wont load without proper authorization token, since that one is not public available.

To further test, use the public API `https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=`

You will be able to get response without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error indicates that you need to add (basic) authentication to your HTTP request (and remove the cookie that you added):

```
String username = “username”;
String password = “password”;

String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + “:” + password));
WebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = “Basic ” + credentials;
```